# Hiding both a label and control based on partial ARIA lable

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The code:

```
<label id="default_cmi_id-AriaId">control:</label>
<select aria-labelledby="default_cmi_id-AriaId">...</select>
```

The only info known piece is the first part of the label id: `default_cmi_id`, actually the last part is used, but that is done by a subsystem so I would prefer not to rely on it.

With that I can find the label with `$("[id^='default_cmi_id']")`

Is there a way in one statement to find both the label and the control and set their enabled or disabled state?

Comment: Try using a comma, `$("[id^='default_cmi_id'], [aria-labelledby ^= 'default_cmi_id']")`

Comment: If they are siblings, `$('[id^="default_cmi_id"]').next().andSelf().hide();` http://jsfiddle.net/m75earjm/

Answer (score 1):

You could group multiple selector using comma, see below demo.

```js
$("[id^='default_cmi_id'], [aria-labelledby ^= 'default_cmi_id']").css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="default_cmi_id-AriaId">control:</label>
<select aria-labelledby="default_cmi_id-AriaId"><option>blah</option></select>
```